# How to modify member from outer class in inner class in RecycleView

Tags: android, static, android-recyclerview

I Have a reciclerview and in each row I have a Button and a text the idea is when the user clicks the button this increments the edittext's value and increment the "uni" which is member of the data pass to the adaptar

my base class Product

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    Integer amount;

    public Product(String name, Integer amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And the adapter

```
public class AdapterProduct extends 

    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProduct.ProductsViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Product> datos;

        public AdapterProduct(ArrayList<Product> datos) {
            this.datos = datos;
        }




        @Override
        public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            ProductsViewHolder pvh = new ProductsViewHolder(item);
            return pvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ProductsViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.textView.setText(datos.get(position).getName());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return datos.size();
        }


        public static class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView textView;
            private EditText edit;
            private Button btn;

            public ProductsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProd);
                edit = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
                btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //increment the value of the text
                        Integer n = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
                        edit.setText(String.valueOf(++n));
                        //here I need increment Product.amount ++
                        // but it is not posible because I am in Static class
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

How can I do this? Iam using the recyclerview is correct? may be other control. pls I am very stucked with this problem that dont let me going to the next things

Answer (score 1):

1. The simple way is just add bind method. And use it on onBindViewHolder

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textView;
    private EditText edit;
    private Button btn;

    public ProductsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProd);
        edit = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
        btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
    }

    public void bind(Product product) {
        textView.setText(product.getName())
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //increment the value of the text
            Integer n = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText(String.valueOf(++n));
            product.setAmount(++n);
            //here I need increment Product.amount ++
             // but it is not posible because I am in Static class
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

2. You can create some kind of ViewBinder. And use it on onBindViewHolder. So all your buisness logic will be on one class and Views on another.

```
public static class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;
    EditText edit;
    Button btn;

    public ProductsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProd);
        edit = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
        btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
    }

}
```

```
public static class ProductsViewBinder {

    public void bind(final ProductsViewHolder viewHolder, final Product product) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(product.getName())
        viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //increment the value of the text
                Integer n = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edit.getText().toString());
                viewHolder.edit.setText(String.valueOf(++n));
                product.setAmount(++n);
                //here I need increment Product.amount ++
                // but it is not posible because I am in Static class
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3. Remove all buisness logic from your Adapter to any Controller (Activity/Fragment etc) or to a Presenter. As answered [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503685/1013428). It is a better way. An Adapter should know only how to bind views.

```
    public interface Callback {
        void onButtonClickListener(Product product);
    }

    public static class ProductsViewBinder {

        public void bind(final ProductsViewHolder viewHolder, final Product product, Callback callback) {
            viewHolder.textView.setText(product.getName())
            viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //increment the value of the text
                    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.edit.getText().toString());
                    viewHolder.edit.setText(String.valueOf(++n));
                    callback.onButtonClickListener(product);
                    /*
                    Or you can pass a potison to onButtonClickListener by using viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()
                    */
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: but if I pass product object I dont know what object is in the array list

Comment: Thanks I will try it soon

Answer (score 0):

define an interface class like this :

```
public interface yourInterface {
   void onButtonCliked() ;
```

}

now in your activity where call the adapter class implement this inter face like this :

```
pulic class yourActivity extends AppComptaActivity implement yourInterface{


//your stuff 

@override
 public void onButtonClicked(){
  // increase your data here      
}
}
```

now create new constructor for your adapter class as like this :

```
yourInterface mInterface ; // local var 
public AdapterProduct(yourInterface interface){ mInterface = interface}
```

And :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(datos.get(position).getName());

        mInterface.onButtonClicked() ;

    }
```

Finally :

now in the activity class modify to :

```
AdapterProduct yourAdapter = new AdapterProduct(this) ;
```

Comment: I think you meant to put a `setOnClickListener()` in your `onBindViewHolder()`. Otherwise your going to get the callback called when the view is bound, not when it's clicked. Also you are not passing which item was clicked.